# Why doesn't the if condition inside the for loop doesn't run?

Tags: java, if-statement

The code basically generates a Pincode and asks the user to write it. Then displays whether the input is correct or not. Also, if the user got it right after one or two trials it should display "you succeeded to guess your Pincode in (one or two) trials"

```java
package assign4;
import java.util.*;

public class assign4 {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int min = 999;
        int max = 10000;
        int generatedPin = (int) (Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        System.out.println("Please enter the pincode sent to you " + generatedPin);
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        if (input == generatedPin) {
          System.out.println("you succeeded to guess your pincode in one trial");
        }
        for(int i = 0; input != generatedPin && i<3; i++) {
          if (i==0) {
            System.out.println("wrong pin! two trial left!");
            input = sc.nextInt();
          } else
```

Why doesn't the following `if` condition run?

```
                if (i==1) {
                System.out.println("wrong pin! one trial left!");
                input = sc.nextInt();
                    if (input == generatedPin) {
                        System.out.println("you succeeded to guess your pincode in 1 trial");
                    }
                }
```

---

```
else 
                    if (i==2)
                        System.out.println("wrong pin! we will lock your account");     
        }
}}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer because as it is right now it is rather difficult to read your full code, which we need if you want us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: The full code is necessary to run the specific if condition which is the center of this post.

Comment: However, I can explain it more to you. First, we take the user input, if it is equal to the generated pin then print a message and don’t enter the for loop.  If the input is not equal to the pin then, print the input is incorrect. Then the user will have only two attempts. If the second attempt was correct, the output should be “you succeeded to guess your code in 1 trial”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood the requirements correctly the following code will do what you need:

```java
public class assign4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int min = 999;
        int max = 10000;
        int generatedPin = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        System.out.println("Please enter the pincode sent to you " + generatedPin);
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        if (input == generatedPin) {
            System.out.println("you succeeded to guess your pincode in one trial");
        } else {
            System.out.println("wrong pin! two trial left!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    input = sc.nextInt();
                    if (input == generatedPin) {
                        System.out.println("you succeeded to guess your pincode in two trials");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("wrong pin! one trial left!");
                    }
                } else {
                    input = sc.nextInt();
                    if (input == generatedPin) {
                        System.out.println("you succeeded to guess your pincode in three trials");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("wrong pin! we will lock your account");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As in my comment, your code is hard to read and I was not. even able to make it compile.

Basically what you need is a for loop that runs two times so that the user has a total of 3 trials to guess the pincode. If in the first one he guesses it you need to exist the for loop. If he fails again, the for loop will run one last time.

Comment: your code works correctly. However, it is missing one `}` at the end.

Comment: Are you sure, I've just copied it and it seems that no `}` is missing ;)

Comment: sorry I copied only 5 `}` because one was hidden...Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

as in your loop condition you have set, the loop will immediately break if input == generatedPin and therefore 'if' becomes unreachable code

Comment: The input is inside `if` so, when we get the input the second time (after the user's input is wrong for the first time) the second loop shouldn’t reach the end until all the actions are done. and the actions are the print statement.